# Can I interact with Phriction via Git?

Tags: git, wiki, phabricator

Some wikis and wiki subsystems use Git as a backend (ikiwiki, Gogs...)

Is it possible to interact with Phriction (wiki subsystem of Phabricator) via Git? In other words, changes via the Phriction web interface appear in `origin/master`, and changes merged into `origin/master` appear in the web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phriction is a database backed wiki, not a file based wiki with git managing the history. So this method of interaction is not possible.